# FactoryGirl attribute value not populated on ActiveRecord class instance

Tags: ruby, activerecord, factory-bot

I have a FactoryGirl factory defining some default values for an ActiveRecord::Base class. All of the values except one are making it to the instantiated class except for one.

Here is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :office, :class => Office do
    open_date '03/01/2011'
    set_up_date '04/28/2011'
    type_code 'D'
  end

  after(:build) do |office|
    puts "Office open_date: #{office.open_date}"
    puts "Office set_up_date: #{office.set_up_date}"
  end
end
```

Here is my base class:

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I do FactoryGirl.build :office, I get the following output:

```
Office open_date: 2011-01-03 00:00:00 -0500
Office set_up_date:
```

Both columns are DATE datatypes on the database. For some reason, only open_date is getting populated on the base class. I have not, so far, been able to determine why. Since I am only calling build, I think I can safely assume that there is no kind of interference from a database trigger.

Any ideas what would cause set_up_date to not get populated on the class instance?

Versions:

```
activemodel (3.2.11)
activerecord (3.2.11)
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.1)
activesupport (3.2.11)
factory_girl (4.2.0)

JRuby 1.7.2 (Running Ruby in 1.9 mode)
```

Thanks

Comment: No idea if it's significant in this case since I can't test right now, but I'd add a space between `set_up_date` and `'04/28/2011'` in `set_up_date'04/28/2011'`.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a type-o when making the example. The code is not like that. But good eye ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just out of curiousity, would your try `set_up_date '28/04/2011'` instead of `04/28/2011`? It looks like `FactoryGirl` understands your input as `DD/MM/YYYY` according to:

```
Office open_date: 2011-01-03 00:00:00 -0500
```

See **01-03** not **03-01** there?

Comment: I didn't even notice that! Ha! That was indeed the problem. I didn't even pay attention to that because it worked fine under FactoryGirl 2.x. We are upgrading, and it seems that FG is no longer "flexible" with date formats. Or maybe its ActiveRecord that had been made pickier about date formats since 3.2.10?

Thanks man! Sometimes you just need another objective set of eyes.

Comment: ActiveRecord 3.1.10 I mean. We upgraded from 3.1.10 to 3.2.11.

Comment: “Sometimes you just need another objective set of eyes.” — sure!